# Is there a way to determine the pure functions?

Tags: bash

I need the ability to define functions to receive a error message if the function tries to change a global variable.

Can I achieve this?

Comment: Now you know why global variables are bad :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. However, you can make global variables readonly with `declare -r`, eg:

```
declare -r cheese='nice'
```

If you then try to modify `$cheese`:

```
cheese='bad'
```

You will get an error:

```
bash: cheese: readonly variable
```

You can use this to prevent functions from changing variables, forcing them to make a local copy if they need to use a variable.

Comment: Instead of `declare -r cheese='nice'` you can also use the `readonly` builtin, i.e. `readonly cheese='nice'`.

Answer (score 0):

In both BASH and Kornshell, you can use `typedef` to define a variable that's strictly local in functions. I believe BASH has an alias to the `typedef` command called `local` that does the same thing.

This will prevent your functions from defining global variables.